# Pygame: Sprites are only drawing the last of the three objects

Tags: python, json, pygame

I am trying to make a stage builder that will ease with the development of adding objects, individually check for their collision, and so forth for every single object, I add-in code.

My idea is to place objects in groups and have their data be retrieved from JSON data. While it seemed that it works from gathering and placing data as I have coded, it only just wants to draw the very last object there. Meaning if I were to have 100 objects with their respective data in JSON, only the 100th object will be drawled.

In that case, I, of course, want to have all the 99th other objects be also drawled.

From the code that I have posted below, I have checked in a print statement that I indeed got the three object data, ''. This should mean that the JSON data itself is not the problem.

If I have to guess, I think the problem is the conversion of individuals and adding them in Groups(); StartHorizontalObjectRepeats() function could be the problem.

Here is a minimum, reproducible code, recreated from my main program.

Codes:

**main.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import StartupSettings
import mechanic as m
from object import HorizontalObject
from pygame.sprite import Group

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    Settings = StartupSettings()

    Objects = HorizontalObject(Settings.screen)
    Objects = Group()

    m.HorizontalObjectRepeats(Settings.screen, Objects)

    while True:
        m.Refresh(Settings, Objects)
```

**settings.py**

```
import pygame

class StartupSettings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
        self.background = [70,70,70]
```

**object.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class HorizontalObject(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super().__init__()

        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('img_test_object.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

**mechanic.py**

```
import pygame
import json
from object import HorizontalObject

def HorizontalObjectRepeats(screen, ObjectExport):
    '''Initates the repeats of given horizontal test objects.'''
    NumberOfObjects = ReadJSONFileGeneral(1)
    for PlacementsofObjects in range(NumberOfObjects):
        StartHorizontalObjectRepeats(screen, ObjectExport, NumberOfObjects)

def StartHorizontalObjectRepeats(screen, ObjectExport, NumberOfObjects):
    '''Starts the repeat.'''
    Object = HorizontalObject(screen)

    for i in range(NumberOfObjects):
        Object.rect = ReadJSONFileObject(0, i)

    ObjectExport.add(Object)
    print(ObjectExport)

def StageBuilderTemplate(templateKeycode):
    '''Template data when starting out the stage builder.'''
    dictObjects = {"HorizontalObjectsData": {0: (50, 50, 308, 76), 1: (100, 100, 308, 76), 2: (150, 150, 308, 76)}}
    dictGeneral = {"BackgroundColor": (255, 0, 255), "HorizontalObjects": len(dictObjects["HorizontalObjectsData"].keys())}

    if templateKeycode == 0:
        return dictGeneral        
    elif templateKeycode == 1:
        return dictObjects

def CreateJSONFile(jsonCreationKeycode):
    '''Dumps data to the specified json based on the sented keycode.'''
    if jsonCreationKeycode == 0:
        with open('General.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(StageBuilderTemplate(0), f)
    elif jsonCreationKeycode == 1:
        with open('Object.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(StageBuilderTemplate(1), f)     

def ReadJSONFileObject(keycode, Repeats):
    '''Attempts to read Object.json file. It will create Object.json
    if it does not exist.

    After reading and extracting the entire data from Object.json,
    it will sent on specific data based on the sented keycode.'''
    try:
        with open("Object.json", 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            if keycode == 0:
                return data["HorizontalObjectsData"].get(str(Repeats))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        CreateJSONFile(1)

def ReadJSONFileGeneral(jsonGeneralKeycode):
    '''Attempts to read General.json file. It will create General.json
    if it does not exist.

    After reading and extracting the entire data from General.json,
    it will sent on specific data based on the sented keycode.'''
    try:
        with open("General.json", 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            if jsonGeneralKeycode == 0:
                return data.get('BackgroundColor')
            elif jsonGeneralKeycode == 1:
                return data.get('HorizontalObjects')
    except FileNotFoundError:
            CreateJSONFile(0)

def Refresh(Settings, Objects):
    '''Updates the screen'''
    Settings.screen.fill(Settings.background)
    Objects.draw(Settings.screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**General.json**

```
{"BackgroundColor": [255, 0, 255], "HorizontalObjects": 3}
```

**Object.json**

```
{"HorizontalObjectsData": {"0": [50, 50, 308, 76], "1": [100, 100, 308, 76], "2": [150, 150, 308, 76]}}
```

**Object Image:**

[image: Object Image]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Notes:

- I understand that the creation of new JSON files, specifically General.json, will have to crash once, before having the program be running back to normal. This is not related to this current problem that I am asking for help.
- For the output, *(Not Responding)* cannot also be related as I do not have this similar occurrence on my main program.

Comment: `return data["HorizontalObjectsData"].get(str(Repeats))` here you seem to get a single result from json file instead of a list due to the use of 'get' method. feel free to ignore if it is not relevant

Comment: @Kingsley yes they do, its all in `StartHorizontalObjectRepeats()`

Comment: @KaanE. It's how I use to indiviually set the rect for each different horizontal objects, unless there is a much better solution for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `StartHorizontalObjectRepeats` function, when you get the rect for the object, you loop through all the objects and get the rect, meaning, they all have the same rect and are in the same spot.

To fix this:

```
def HorizontalObjectRepeats(screen, ObjectExport):
    '''Initates the repeats of given horizontal test objects.'''
    NumberOfObjects = ReadJSONFileGeneral(1)
    for PlacementsofObjects in range(NumberOfObjects):
        StartHorizontalObjectRepeats(screen, ObjectExport, PlacementsofObjects) #changed the last parameter

def StartHorizontalObjectRepeats(screen, ObjectExport, objNum):
    '''Starts the repeat.'''
    Object = HorizontalObject(screen)

    Object.rect = ReadJSONFileObject(0, objNum) # get the nth objects rect

    ObjectExport.add(Object)
```

Comment: Your answer works as the desired output I was expected. Thank you very much, as this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In the first function in mechanic.py the first function has a for loop in range(blah) that calls the second function which for loops in range(blah) again and based on your description isn’t implemented correctly. Can you get just one of the json files to display singly ? I would try and start there and once you have that working properly implementation new features And from there try and figure out to use the classes and sprites

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify your statement again? From what I can understand, your solution sounds similar to The Big Kahuna's.

Comment: The answer above was what I was getting at, his is much more concise lol